# virtual host opening another virtual host

Tags: zend-framework2, virtualhost

host name:dhs

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot "/var/www/dhs/public/"
   ServerName dhs

   # This should be omitted in the production environment
   SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development

   <Directory "/var/www/dhs/public/">
       Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
       AllowOverride All
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
   </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

host name: deforay

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot "/var/www/deforay/public/"
   ServerName deforay

   # This should be omitted in the production environment
   SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development

   <Directory "/var/www/deforay/public/">
       Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
       AllowOverride All
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
   </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

but dhs(e.g: dhs/) opening the deforay host , am using in zend framework 2, the "deforay" host is working good but not dhs... i also added dhs in hosts's file

Answer (score 1):

your config seems valid, the only way that may could be wrong is that you don't activated named based virtual hosts.

to get that work insert into your `vhost` config file `NameVirtualHost *:80` (edit the port if you use a different one)

make sure your `host` file includes

```
127.0.0.1    dhs
127.0.0.1    deforay
```

and access your webpage in your browser with

```
http://dhs
http://deforay
```